# Don't stage or commit a file that contains certain text

Tags: git

Is there a way to globally omit files from being staged or commited if they contain specific text?

Globally meaning independent of workspace/cwd

For example:

```
//@NOCHECKIN
//TODO: test performance
var numbers = new List<int> { args };
decimal average = numbers.Aggregate(
    seed: 0,
    func: (result, item) => result + item,
    resultSelector: result => (decimal)result / numbers.Count);
```

The keyword here, '@NOCHECKIN', omitting the file from staging.

I would love to automate this by doing a simple `git add .` and not worry about it.
Currently I have been using `git add -i` and stepping through

---

**Re globally**: As pointed out this may have to be done per repository, I personally don't know, but I found a work-around that suits my needs. I just created a template dir with the `pre-commit` hook; now anytime I clone or do `git init` the hook is automatically included with the repos.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.  Git assumes that you know what you're doing when you stage a file and doesn't second guess you.

While it isn't possible to prevent a file from being staged, it is possible to use a `pre-commit` hook that uses `git diff-index HEAD` to find the files that have changed since the last commit and abort the commit if the file contains an appropriate entry.  You'd need to do this on a per-repository basis unless you set `core.hooksPath` either globally or for the repositories you care about to use a shared hooks directory.

Comment: Well git is right, I *do know* that I don't want to stage it :P You can do this with SVN scripts just seeing if there are ways to emulate with git CLI or VSCode, but I think their hook scripts work the same? Let me review some reading material on the hooks and if that isn't sufficient I'll post a bounty for any of the `thinking out-of-the-box` answers. Thanks a lot for the swift reply

Comment: @soulshined There is no staging area in SVN, so this would be impossible there anyways. The equivalent of what you could do with SVN would be the `pre-commit` hook as OP mentioned.

Comment: After reading up on it, this fits perfectly; even figured a way to go this 'globally'. Thank you very much bk!

Answer (score 10):

In `pre-commit`, you can reset a staged file from the index if the file contains the keyword, so that the file won't be committed. A sample `pre-commit` could be like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get the staged files
s_files=$(git diff --name-only --cached)

# if a staged file contains the keyword, get it out of the staged list
for s_file in ${s_files};do
    if grep -q -E '@NOCHECKIN' ${s_file};then
        echo "WARNING: ${s_file} contains the keyword"
        git reset ${s_file}
    fi
done

# if there is not any staged file left, fail the commit, otherwise
# an empty commit would be created.
s_files=$(git diff --name-only --cached)
if [[ "${s_files}" = "" ]];then
    echo "WARNING: nothing to commit"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: I haven't thoroughly tested but at a high level this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: After using this past month or two, this has worked very well in my daily workflow, so thank you. It even acts accordingly with `--force` (well at least what I expect to happen with force). Hasn't been any drawbacks to date personally

Comment: One note: you should probably use `git grep -q -E @NOCHECKIN :$s_file` (using `git`'s grep so it can access the staged content, and adding the leading colon so it gets the staged content's id from the index and reads that rather whatever's at that path in the work tree at the moment).

Comment: @jthill and ElpieKay, I made a repository for this with some minor changes. https://github.com/clankill3r/NOCHECKIN More info about what and why there.

Comment: You should use `git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=d` else you get errors when checking in files you deleted.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really adequate, but: a *clean filter* could notice the `//@NOCHECKIN` and replace the entire file contents with an empty string, or just the `//@NOCHECKIN`.  You could then (and/or also) test for such files in pre-commit and pre-push hooks as well, as [bk2204 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59132042/1256452).

It probably makes more sense to have such a clean filter generate a warning.  That would be your notice that you should `git rm --cached` the file and then list it in a `.gitignore`.

You can also mark a clean filter as "required".  I have never tested this to see how it works in practice, nor looked closely enough at the source to predict how it would work in theory.

See [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for details on setting up a clean filter.